# In PHP generate a random but unique string to by-pass browser caching

Tags: php, caching, time

Most of you will know that when you have enabled caching it is hard to see changes that you've made to your files. For instance, your stylesheet doesn't reflect the changes you've made to it. A solution is to append a "version number", something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=2">
```

However, always setting this value manually is quite the hassle. A solution I came up with is to let PHP generate a unique value before each cache. The most straightforward way to do this would be to create a number based on the date. More specifically I would consider the time the PHP file is last updated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='css/styles.css?v=<?php echo date("ymd-Gi", getlastmod()) ?>'>
```

This would still require me to save the PHP file each time I save the CSS file, but I suppose it's in each case a lot easier than to manual set the version number.

I am wondering if there is an easier way in PHP to do this. The best way, obviously, would be to check when the *stylesheet* was last modified and construct a version number based on that. Is that possible?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.http-cache-etag.php

Comment: Is this a debug question? Because it would be way easier to just disable your browser's caching.

Comment: @Robert If you could expand on how to use that, I can take a look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `getlastmod()`, which checks the modification date of the PHP script, you could use `filemtime($css_filename)` ([documentation on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)) to obtain the last modification of the css file.

For instance, this would be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='css/styles.css?v=<?php echo date("ymd-Gi", filemtime("css/styles.css")) ?>'>
```

assuming that the relative path of the browser corresponds to the relative path on your server (change to internal location, if otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

**uniqid()** is a PHP function that generates a unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds. You can depend on that.

```
echo uniqid();
```

Comment: Note that this disables caching completely – if you want the browser to reload only if the script is changed on server side, this won't help you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
<link href="/stylesheet.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Note that this disables caching completely – if you want the browser to reload **only** if the script is changed on server side, this won't help you!